# Retrieve MIME multipart data from a SOAP response

Tags: python, soap, mime

I'm using Python and Suds to consume a SOAP webservice, and sometimes, when the response data is too big, it switch the response format to [`WS-Attachment`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments). It's supposed to be a full MIME message, but instead, I only get the "boundary" parts, like this:

```
------=_Part_2_27050467.1235668849951
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <0F082AF1DAF83B3077B1867B4FC8AAA6>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:runReportResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://axis2.ws.jasperserver.jaspersoft.com">
        <runReportReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;\n&lt;operationResult version=&quot;2.0.1&quot;&gt;\n\t&lt;returnCode&gt;&lt;![CDATA[0]]&gt;&lt;/returnCode&gt;\n&lt;/operationResult&gt;\n
        </runReportReturn>
    </ns1:runReportResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
------=_Part_2_27050467.1235668849951
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <report>

%PDF-1.4\n%âãÏÓ\n1 0 obj <</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 29>>stream\nx+är\ná26S°00S\bIár\rá\näâ
```

How to properly extract both parts of the response? None of the Python's email module clases plays nice with this data, they all asume it's one big string. I was expecting something like:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary=_Part_2_27050467.1235668849951; type=text/xml;
        start="<some@domain.com>"
Content-Description: This is the optional message description.
```

at the beginning of the response, but only that comes in.